# facebook notification icons for a javafx tab

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

How can I show the little red icons, which are known from Facebook and notify about new messages, friend request etc. in a Tab of a JavaFX Application?
This is what I tried so far:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="200" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
      <TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="220.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="TestTab"/>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
    <StackPane AnchorPane.leftAnchor="58.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0">
      <children>
        <Ellipse opacity="0.51" radiusX="9.0" radiusY="8.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.5">
          <fill>
            <LinearGradient endX="0.95" endY="0.5" startY="0.5">
              <stops>
                <Stop color="#0096c9" />
                <Stop color="#3ec5ee" offset="1.0" />
              </stops>
            </LinearGradient>
          </fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" prefWidth="20.0" text="3">
          <font>
            <Font size="10.0" />
          </font>
        </Label>
      </children>
    </StackPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I don't think it's a good solution, because the StackPane is placed absolutely and is independent of the Tab. If the Tab gets moved or resized or removed or whatever, the Notification-StackPane might be placed wrong. It would be complex to handle these cases.

Setting the Notification-StackPane with `javafx.scene.control.Tab#setGraphic` seems to be the wrong way since I don't know how to position the graphic. Is there a way to let the graphic overlap the Tab, so that a part of the graphic is outside the tab? It should look similar to the fxml-example above.
And extending the Tab or one of the TabHeader Skins seems to be hard work ;) My Experience is, that many of the interesting and relevant methods are private or final in JavaFX core-classes. Do you have any nice idea?

Comment: Using `Tab.setGraphic` (or the equivalent in FXML) is probably the right way to do this. Can you edit your question to show what you tried for that and explain what happened.

Comment: Hey James_D, see above for my explanation